# Best way to extract sub-types from JSON string in Typescript

Tags: json, typescript

I am trying to find the best way to extract sub-types from a JSON string. For example let's say you receive the following response back from the server:

```
{
  "isEnabled": true,
  "alpha": 1.0,
  "backgroundColor": "#ffffff",
  "clipToBounds": false,
  "text": "A random lorem epsum",
  "textAlignment": "left",
  "font": "Sans Serif",
  "fontSize": 16.0,
  "cornerRadius": 4.0,
  "shadowColor": "#000000",
  "shadowRadius": 2.0,
  "shadowOffsetY": 2.0,
  "shadowOffsetX": 0.0,
  "border": 2.0,
  "borderColor": "#444444"
}
```

I would like to extract the above `JSON` string into the following types in `Typescript`:

```js
interface CornerRadiusStyle {
  cornerRadius: number
}

interface ShadowStyle {
  shadowColor: string 
  shadowRadius: number
  shadowOffsetX: number 
  shadowOffsetY: number 
}

interface BorderStyle {
  border: number 
  borderColor: string 
}

interface LayerStyle {
  cornerRadiusStyle: CornerRadiusStyle
  shadowStyle: ShadowStyle
  borderStyle: BorderStyle 
}

interface Style {
  backgroundColor: string 
  clipToBounds: boolean 
  layerStyle: LayerStyle 
}

interface View {
  style: Style
  isEnabled: boolean
  alpha: number
}

interface TextStyle {
  textAlignment: string 
  font: string 
  fontSize: number 
}

interface Label extends View {
  text: string 
  textStyle: TextStyle
}
```

So you would eventually end up being able to do the following:

```js
const label: Label = JSON.parse(/* customized parsing */);
const textStyle = label.textStyle;
const text = label.text;
const style = label.style;
const alpha = label.alpha;
```

How might I go about accomplishing this? I have used `revivers` but it still seems like a convoluted process and I was hoping some of the experts on here could enlighten on a simpler and conciser process to do this :)

Comment: What do you mean with "extract differen sub-types"? If you know the JSON response, you can just say `type AllStyles = Label & Style & TextStyle ..` and cast it as `const styles = JSON.parse(response.text) as AllStyles`

Comment: I'm looking for a typesafe manner to ensure that only those properties pertaining to each interface sub-type is there. Care to post an answer below if you think your answer is sufficient? I believe my question has all the necessary information to explain what I'm asking for. In the type safe world (say Swift) you have to specify types for your JSON decoding.